# How to install pfx certificate in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, silverlight-5.0, pfx

Personal Information Exchange (PFX) key files (.pfx) file has been created.How to attach that file into visual studio 2012 Solution. I din't find signing Tab in VS2012.

Comment: VS2012 PRO does not showing Silverlight 5 signing project properties

Answer (score 1):

VS2012 PRO Is having bug , It has been fixed and completed the Signing pfx file in Silverlight Application. [More Info...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31669850/how-to-signing-xap-file-using-pfx-in-silverlight-application)