# How to Signing xap file using pfx in Silverlight Application

Tags: visual-studio-2012, silverlight-5.0

I have created a silver-light Application using Visual Studio 2012.I'm not getting Signing page in the project properties. How to configure pfx file in silverlight 5.

[image]

Comment: Singing Tab is present Next to reference paths, While clicking that tab i'm getting  "An error occurred trying to load the page. Class not registered. Looking for object with CLSID: {B07DA5DD-055B-4018-88F3-3A433FDB9B25}"

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio is looking for in for a register key named {B07DA5DD-055B-4018-88F3-3A433FDB9B25}.VS 2012 Pro's installer doesn't create this key.So we need to create this registry-key manually ,

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\CLSID\{B07DA5DD-055B-4018-88F3-3A433FDB9B25}
(OR)
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config\CLSID\{B07DA5DD-055B-4018-88F3-3A433FDB9B25}
```

- "Class" = "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Silverlight.SigningPropertyPageComClass"
- "Assembly" = "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Silverlight, Version=11.0.0.0,
  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
- "ThreadingModel" = "Both"
- "InprocServer32" = "c:\Windows\SysWOW64\mscoree.dll"
- "Default" = "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Silverlight.SigningPropertyPageComClass"

[image]

Comment: If you are getting "An error occurred trying to load the page.
Unable to create the designer.  File is already opened in an incompatible editor". Just restart your machine and try again.